# Как получить объект из RestController Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, angular, spring-data

Есть model Tourist в которой есть связь с model Flight:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String sex;
private String country;
private String notes;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "tourist_flight",
        joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "tourist_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "flight_id"))
private Set<Flight> flights;
```

model Flight:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private LocalDateTime timeOfDeparture;
private LocalDateTime arrivalTime;
private int numberOfSeats;
@ManyToMany
private Set<Tourist> tourists;
private double ticketPrice;
```

в Controller получаю этот объект по id

```
@GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
public Tourist editTourist(@PathVariable long id){
    return this.touristService.editTourist(id);
}
```

Метод editTourist(long id):

```
public Tourist editTourist(long id) {
    return this.touristRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}
```

Angular app:

model Tourist:

```
export interface Tourist {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  sex: string;
  country: string;
  notes: string;
  flights: Flight[];
}
```

model Flight:

```
export interface Flight {
  id: number;
  timeOfDeparture: Date;
  arrivalTime: Date;
  numberOfSeats: number;
  tourists: Tourist[];
  ticketPrice: number;
}
```

В tourist.service.ts получаю объект Tourist:

```
getTouristById(id: number): Observable<Tourist>{
    return this.http.get<Tourist>(this.GET_TOURIST_BY_ID_URL + id);
}
```

В tourist.component.ts

```
 constructor(private touristService: TouristService, router: Router, activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
this.id = activeRoute.snapshot.params.id;
}

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.edit(this.id);
  }
  public edit( id: number) {
    this.touristService.getTouristById(id).subscribe(
      res => {
         console.log(res);
      },
      error => {console.log('An error'); }
    );
  }
```

В результате чего получаю:
[image: Результат]

Как можно увидеть есть 1 элемент, но неизвестно какой, как его можно получить?

Вывод в консоль на сервере:

[image: Тест]

Comment: Тебе нужно получить объект на фронте?

Comment: @Jackson750 да, для дальнейшей манипуляции данными

Comment: Ответил, по идеи проблем нету

Comment: @Jackson750 делал так, результат тот же, все данные получаються нормально, но масив flights только видно length

Comment: Со связью в таблицах проблем нету?  Вывод ответа делал на беке в консоли?

Comment: @Jackson750 там все хорошо, обновил вопрос с выводом на сервере

Comment: обновил ответ, чекни

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104455/discussion-between-jackson750-and-kzz-xd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> У меня все хорошо связало

```
  ngOnInit() {
 this.http.get<Tourist>('http://localhost:8081/edit/1').subscribe(
  res => {
  this.tour = res;
  console.log(res);
  },
  error => {console.log('An error'); }
);

 console.log(this.tour);
```

}
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]